# How to subscribe an observable who needs another hot subscription - RxJava

Tags: java, kotlin, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I  need to subscribe to an observable who needs another observable to subscribe. Something like:

```
val someSingle = Single.create<Response>{singleEmmiter ->
        dataStream.subscribe {elementInDataStream->
            if(elementInDataStream == "somethingiwant"){
                .
                .
                .
                val someresponse = //someCode
                singleEmmiter.onSuccess(someResponse)
            }
        }
    }
```

I have to something like that because in the dataStream i can have anything and maybe i can use more than one element of the dataStream object (so i think i cannot do opperations like filter on the dataStream).
Where the dataStream is an instance of **ConnectableObservable (Hot observable)**

```
val dataStream = listOf("hello","world", "somethingiwant").toObservable().publish()
```

Then i have something like:

```
someSingle.blockingGet()
dataStream.connect()
```

This code will never end because someSingle is generating blocking wait and is wating for some elemement in the dataStream but the dataStream is not sending any element yet. Generating an infinit block.

If i change the code like this:

```
dataStream.connect()   
someSingle.blockingGet()
```

It generates a concurrency problem because maybe the element 
**"somethingiwant"** was already published on the hot observable so my block will never end.

Maybe some solution is to use **ReplaySubject** instead of **ConnectableObservable** but i think is not an optimal solution.

**Note: I need to use a blocking get because the response that i want from the blocking get is the controller response.**

Comment: Why don't `flatMap` the `Single` to the other `Observable`?

Comment: Because maybe in some cases the someSingle will use two elemens of the dataStream, maybe will use the data given by "hello" but also needs to use the data given from "world" and need the both data to generate the `Single.just("hello world")` . How i would do that?

Comment: It not clear in your question what you're trying to archive, Even though your code is equivalent to `val someSingle = dataStream.filter { it == "somethingiwant" }.map {...}.singleOrError()`

Comment: Yes, but in your answer in the **map**  i will only have the the scope of the element **"somethingiwant"** if i do something like: `someSingle = dataStream.filter { it == "hello" || it == "world" }.map {...}.singleOrError() ` i would only have the scoope of the hello and world in separate scopes i need to have the two elements in the same scope, something like a zip. but idk how to archive that.

Comment: That's not what you are asking in your question, Then indeed you can use zip operator `val someSingle = Observables.zip(dataStream.filter { it == "hello" }, dataStream.filter { it == "world" })
        .map { (a, b) ->"$a $b" }
        .singleOrError()`

Comment: My advice is, avoid subscribing to an `Observable` inside another, most of the time yo can get the same result by composing them

Comment: Thanks for your time and your answer. `Observables.zip(dataStream.filter { it == "hello" }, dataStream.filter { it == "world" }) .map { (a, b) ->"$a $b" } .singleOrError()` works for me. You are right, is much better opperate over the observable instead doing another subscription. I was thinking i couldn't operate over the observable.